# Express / Pug - How to strip comments?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using Express with Pug as a view engine.

Pug renders comments in the HTML. For example:

```
div
  // comment
  p Hello
```

Would be rendered as:

```
<div>
  <!--comment-->
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

How would I disable this functionality and instead strip them from the template so that they aren't visible in the rendered HTML?

I can see there is this [pug-strip-comments](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/tree/master/packages/pug-strip-comments) package, but there is no documentation whatsoever for Express.

I want to avoid using something like a middleware to strip comments.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip pug comments by using the following code. Just add //- instead of just // and it will strip it from from the rendered HTML.

```
//- will NOT output within markup
p foo
p bar

// will output within markup
p foo
p bar
```

You can take a look at the comments documentation for pug here:
https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html